# chrome extension: load external web page as as if it were in its domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I've created a Google Chrome Extension for personal usage, and I would like load external web page as if it were in its domain.

In example, suppose that I inject the content script `mydomain.js` when tab url match `mydomain.com`, and in that case I would load the external web page `externaldomain.com/articles.html` to parse this page when it's loaded.

I know that tipically this goal is reached via `iframe` or `XMLHttpRequest`, but both don't work. I think that `externaldomain.com/articles.html`perform some check that fails if not loaded in its own domain.

Someone has an idea about how simulate loading of `externaldomain.com/articles.html` like tab is in `externaldomain.com` ?

**Extra:**

actually my trick is open directly `externaldomain.com/articles.html` in a tab and inject a script (`myextension-externaldomain.js`): when tab is loaded this script parse the page, and then pass the result to `mydomain.js` via [chrome messages passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).
It works, but It's very awkward!

Comment: If you don't mean to show the html  and just want to parse its response, you could moving your xhr logic to background page, they are not restricted by SOP. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: my problem isn't due to origin policy error. My parse starts on window loads, and the right load happens only if I'm in that domain, otherwise the request goes right, but the appended responseText fails load it's scripts. Anyhow, thanks!